# Stuck on Ubuntu purple Install page

Tags: installation

I just built my first PC today and I am trying to boot into ubuntu. I do not have windows. It boots up but sits at the purple screen with the dots that go from orange to white. It has been sitting here for awhile. I checked to make sure the files were correctly burned and it looks like they were. I used a DVD-R and burned it using Windows on another pc. Anyone have any ideas, how long should it realistically take to get past this screen. I'm not really sure where I went wrong.

After pressing the arrow I see a bunch of bus error, mountall:failed

Adding 'diversion of /usr/bin/bluetooth-applet to usr/bin/bluetooth-applet.orig by casper'
mountall event failed
]2046.677600] end_request I/O error, dev sr0 sector 158960

this repeats a bunch with varying numbers and codes. I really don't know what to do.

Comment: This information is not enough. we need more information like what are the specifications of your system

Comment: Asus Z87-Pro
Intel i5 - 4670k
No GPU (Planned for 2GB Card)
Corsair R200 case
4GB Ballistix Sport (Planned 12GB)

Comment: What type of graphics Intel or anything ?

Comment: Integrated Intel graphics. I am just using the graphics on the processor. I was told the i5-4670k when I bought it had integrated graphics.

Comment: I added some of the codes the machine is throwing at me in the original question. Its like its trying to install but not doing anything. Should I not have used a DVD?

Answer (score 1):

The error on /dev/sr0 indicates that it's highly likely that you have a corrupt CD/DVD.

First use this page to understand how to check your .iso file (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM), Then make sure you use the verify option on your CD burning software to ensure that the CD is actually correct.

With a new CD (without errors) it should work a whole lot better.

I don't think it's an issue with the CD drive or driver as it's showing up in a later sector (158960), so it's more likely data corruption on download or writing the Disc.